# Subset polygons of a single spatialPolygonsDataFrame row

Tags: r, r-maptools, rworldmap

I want to split a single `spatialPolygonsDataFrame` row that consists of multiple polygon geometries, and I'm not sure about the most sensible way to achieve this.  For example if we want to remove Alaska from `usa` below here, we could filter out polygons with centroid over 50 degrees latitude.  Does anyone know a relatively painless way to do this?

```
require(rworldmap)
require(maptools)
data(countriesCoarse)
usa = countriesCoarse[168, ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `"Spatial-class"` objects, this kind of operation often requires some painfully low-level manipulation of the component data structures. (The larger expectation, of course, is that you'll do this once and then write a nice wrapper function of your own that does exactly what you want the next time you need it done!)

In any case, here's what that lower-level manipulation might look like in your case:

```
## Extract component "Polygon" objects
pp <- usa@polygons[[1]]@Polygons
## Find indices of non-Alaska Polygon objects
ii <- sapply(pp, function(X) mean(coordinates(X)[,2])<50)

## Put desired Polygon objects back together in a built-from-scratch SpatialPolygons obj.
## Note: ID will need to match row name of data.frame attached to SpatialPolygons object
USA49 <-
SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(srl = pp[ii], ID = rownames(data.frame(usa)))),
                proj4string=CRS(proj4string(usa)))
## Reattach attributes in data.frame(usa)
USA49 <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(USA49, data = data.frame(usa))

## Check that it worked
plot(USA49, col="lightgrey")
```

[image]